# Can you specify a sub-sequence for a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've created an item history table for which I'd like to automatically increment `VersionId` partitioned by `ItemId`.

```
ID        ItemId        VersionId        ItemContent        Created
1         1             1                fooo               2015-02-24 12:54:00.11
2         2             1                barr               2015-02-24 12:54:15.35
3         1             2                foo                2015-02-24 12:55:00.61
4         1             3                baz                2015-02-24 12:55:45.23
5         2             2                bar                2015-02-24 12:56:00.03
```

Currently, that `VersionId` is set in a trigger. What I would like to find is something like this (I know this doesn't actually work):

```
create table ItemHistory
(
     Id int identity(1,1) not null primary key
    ,ItemId int not null references Item(Id)
    ,VersionId int not null default row_number() over (partition by ItemId order by Id)
    ,ItemContent varchar(max)
    ,Created datetime not null default getdate()
)
```

While I have a working solution, I'd like to know if I'm missing some built-in functionality for handling this case.

Comment: So are you saying when you write a row into the table you will specify the ItemId and you want the VersionId to be set automatically based upon the rows already in the table?

Comment: @Elliveny Yes, that's right.

Comment: I think a trigger is the answer here. I'm not aware of a better solution. Upvote on the question, I'm keen to see if anyone comes up with anything!

Comment: Why not just do it with a view?  You can have row_number() in a view.

Comment: @blam true. That's probably the better option than mucking about with triggers.

Comment: If you have 3 versions of an item and delete the 2nd version, should version 3 still be version 3, or now be the 'new' 2nd version?

Comment: Items in the version history table will not be updated or deleted; it's an insert-only table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to use my comment as the answer

Why not just do it with a view? You can have row_number() in a view.

With an index on ItemId, Id it should be very fast.
Probably less overhead than trigger.

I see you added a comment read only.  Even more reason for view.

Comment: While certainly better than the trigger, I guess I was hoping for some new-fangled hotness, i.e.: a partioned sequenece as a default constraint.

Comment: A FK iden that sequences for each FK would be sweet.

Comment: I agree.. new-fangled hotness might be needed.  Partitioned sequences sound amazing.